# Twining his hands "in" the spider thread - why "in" instead of "around"?

Tags: prepositions

> Twining his hands **in** the spider thread, Kandata laughed aloud as he had not in all the years since he had come to this place. [— *The Spider Thread*, Ryūnosuke Akutagawa, translated by Jay Rubin](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CEYQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.otisarchimboldi.com%2F2013%2F03%2Fthe-spider-thread-by-ryunosuke-akutagawa-translation-by-jay-rubin%2F&ei=Em-7U-yJA-aO8gG4uYHgDA&usg=AFQjCNF8UB910LYAWnxi1JqdJ3J8VeiF8g&sig2=cSq5u2OYY-qshbLRIsUL3Q&bvm=bv.70138588,d.dGc&cad=rja)

Why is *in* used here instead of *around*?

Comment: Probably because the author wanted to evoke an image of the hands being entwined with the threads of the web. Similar to being tangled in (not on) a web.

Comment: @user8153: yes, but the thread is wrapping _around_ his hands, with him holding them _in_ it.

Comment: Maybe because the image the author wants is the thread wrapping around the hands so the hands are *in* the thread.

Comment: Having checked the source, I agree that 'around' would be more appropriate. 'in' doesn't make sense, as the spider thread is a kind of rope.

Comment: [The original](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000879/files/92_14545.html): 犍陀多は **両手を蜘蛛の糸にからみながら、** ここへ来てから何年にも出した事のない声で、「しめた。しめた。」と笑いました。

Comment: @CoolHandLouis Jay Rubin is a fine translator.  I don't think the quality of the English is any reason to close this question.

Answer (score 4):

Note that just before this Kandata has grown so tired that

> he couldn’t raise his arm for even one more pull. He had no choice but to stop for a rest, and as he clung to the spider thread, he looked down far below.

That is, he had stopped and was gripping the thread closely. When he sees that it is in fact possible to climb out of Hell, he relaxes. So that he need not 'cling' to the thread while he rests, he twists ('twines') his hands, which are still gripping the thread, in such a way that instead of his hand surrounding the thread, *the thread surrounds his hands*: he 'belays' the thread around his own hands. With his hands now 'in' the thread, he can relax his grip, trusting that the tension of his weight on the thread will keep the loops of thread tight so that he does not fall.